# Validation using a while loop

Tags: java, validation, loops, while-loop

Hi people I just need a quick fix on how to do the validation for this question. Unfortunately the book I am using doesnt seem to provide a solution after attempting the program. Here is the the question.

"Write an input validation program that asks the user to enter 'Y', 'y' 'N' or 'n' "

keep in mind it must be done only using a while loop any help would be appreciated.

```
while(answer != "y" || answer!= "n" )
    {
        System.out.println("Please use a  Y or N");
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

that is my current loop but it doesnt seem to work even if i enter y or n in it.

The current output i keep getting is "Please use a  Y or N" regardless if I enter the correct letter

Comment: Also consider using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` , it will manage the case sensitivity for you.

Comment: Besides String comparaison, you should also replace the "or" comparaison `||` with an "and" comparaison `&&`.

Comment: And consider changing the condition to an **&&** and not **||**, it's not doing what you're thinking

Comment: You guys are all wrong. He is asking about something entirely different - he wants to know how to make such loop.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but yes I am asking if someone is able to help me correct my code. I cant use equalsIgnoreCase because thats not on this chapter. Its just using the while loop to do a simple validation is all. I cant use any other tools sadly.

Comment: @Aersor: If you can't use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` (which is a silly requirement) then just use `.equals()` and include all the cases in the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would almost call for a do-while cycle:

```
do {
    answer = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please use a  Y or N");
} while(!answer.equals("y") && !answer.equals("n"))
```

Except for one problem, this shows you the warning anyway. Using while, there are two options:

```
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
while(!answer.equals("y") && !answer.equals("n")) {
    System.out.println("Please use a  Y or N");
    answer = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Or, the "infinite loop with break" approach, that saves you the duplicity, but introduces a "goto":

```
while(true) {
    answer = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("n")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Please use a  Y or N");
}
```

The comparison using `==` is a disaster - never use it with `String`, always use `equals`. Otherwise you are comparing the reference rather than the value.

I almost forgot about the uppercase letters: you can replace `equals` with `equalsIgnoreCase` as mentioned in comments. However if it's not available to you because of the silly requirements, simply make the comparison with `"Y"` and `"N"` as well.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer I have taken the first segement of the code as thats all I am required to do. I will be telling my lecturer tomorrow that I had to use the !.answer.equals("Y") part instead as comparing strings using == is just messy. Thank you so much everyone for the help :)

Comment: If your teacher really told you to use `==` to compare value of String or any object, then he should learn first before teaching. This is a big NOPE in Java.